# Select by attribute not working in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, nunit

I am starting now to use MongoDB in a new project. I have created some tests for a class called `PersistanceManager<C>`. This class is a wrapper of some of MongoDB's features. It is quite simple now, it will expand as we need more functionality.

The problem is that I am stucked with a failing test. It fails with the message "No object was returned". This is the test:

```
[Test, Description("Tests the selection of an object by an attribute.")]
    public void ObjectFieldSelectionTest()
    {
        InstanceTest it = new InstanceTest(5898, "1234");
        PersistanceManager<InstanceTest> pm = new PersistanceManager<InstanceTest>();
        pm.Insert(it);

        InstanceTest[] its = pm.GetInstanceByAttr(1, new KeyValuePair<string, BsonValue>("field", "1234"));

    if (its.Length < 1)
    {
        pm.Delete(it);
        Assert.Fail("No object was returned");
    }
    else
    {
        InstanceTest it2 = its[0];
        pm.Delete(it);
        Assert.AreEqual(it.Field, it2.Field);
    }

}
```

The method I am testing from `PersistantManager<C>` is this one:

```
private MongoCollection<C> collection;

public PersistanceManager()
{
    MongoDatabase db = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost").GetServer().GetDatabase("db");
        collection = db.GetCollection<C>(typeof(C).Name);
}

//This is the method
public C[] GetInstanceByAttr(int amount, KeyValuePair<string, BsonValue> kvp)
{
     MongoCursor<C> cursor = collection.FindAs<C>(Query.EQ(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
     cursor.Limit = amount;

     return cursor.ToArray<C>();
}
```

And the class `InstanceTest` I use for testing is as follows (It is defined in the same class as the tests):

```
private class InstanceTest: IDBStorable
{
    public BsonValue Id { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }

    public InstanceTest() { }

    public InstanceTest(int id, string field)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Field = field;
    }
}
```

All the other tests (select by id, inset, update, delete, multiple inset, etc.) work.
What am I missing?

Comment: Case matters. :) `field` in your query is not `public string Field`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, as WiredPrairie said, case matters. What a silly mistake...